# True Image backup only certain files

Tags: windows-7, backup, acronis-trueimage

After having done a full system backup there are only 4 files that must be backed up on a schedule. Is there a way to setup Acronis True Image 2013 to do this? The computer has Windows 7. Also a backup tries to start automatically on Sundays but takes too long. I can't find where this is set, beside "schedule" in "Disk Backup" it is set to off but it's still happening.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Task Scheduler in your Windows 7 and see if there is any task created for this backup. Also you can create your own tasks to accomplish the backups that you needs.

Comment: Where is the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Control Panel ->Administrative Tools